# apostrophe-headless PUT Requests override empty fields

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I'm building an SPA with apostrophe-headless, Vue and Express as a proxy. What I'm trying to do is to update some fields, depending on what the user changed. To be more specific, I made a members module with several additional fields. Login works via Firebase (frontend) so I have a field with the userId to get a relation. But now, if I edit some fields and send it back to apostrophe, it updates all fields, also that ones I never sent. This is also overriding the userId field (not the _id field) if not permitted. The question:

Is it possible to just change the fields that I sent and furthermore, can I deactivate some fields for not being editable via REST-API? I would also be interested in hiding fields on the backend...

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apostrophe-headless` doesn't currently support a PATCH style request so you need to set your app up to have the entire doc (page or piece), modify it, and send the whole thing back to the API.

Comment: Okay, then that's the way to go. What about the possibility to deactivate fields from editing via REST or backend?